# HTC M8. Can't explore files via windows.

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, mtp, htc-one-m8

My phone is connected over USB to Windows, where it is only recognized as 'Android Phone' under the `unspecified` tab.

On the phone, no notification of USB connections is given at all, except that the phone starts charging. I've tried to enable MTP over USB, but I can't seem to locate the 'Use USB for..' menu anywhere.

Searching for `usb` in the settings menu turns up nothing.

Comment: You should be able to tap the USB notification, which should lead you to the correct menu to switch between MTP, PTP etc. If not, check in *Settings › Storage.*

Comment: @Izzy There's no USB notifaction. In `settings` > `Storage & USB` there are no options related to USB at all :/

Comment: In *Settings › Storage,* have you hit the "overflow menu button" (the 3 "stapled dots" in the upper right corner)? That should pop out an option named like "USB Connection".

Comment: @Izzy Regretfully, there's no such option. The overflow only lists `Help & feedback`